# С чего начать изучение фронтенд разработки? (html, css, js, ...?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Добрый день! Решила начать изучать фронтенд разработку. Думаю, сейчас это довольно перспективно, так ведь? До этого учила JAVA и немного начала изучать Android разработку, но видно, не пошло...

Хочу попробовать данное направление, может оно хорошо пойдет и понравится это дело! Могу ли я начать с Javascript сразу? Если да, то с каких источников или книг начать его изучать? Или до изучения Javascript нужно обязательно знать HTML, CSS?

Comment: Вы знаете HTML и CSS?

Comment: сначала `html5` + `css3` вот тут http://htmlbook.ru / http://webref.ru, через пол года и некоторое кол-во созданных сайтов придёт (должно) достаточное понимание интерфейса и взаимодейтсвия с ним. после этого можно влезать в javascript (например, http://learn.javascript.ru)

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Имхо лучше изучать в таком порядке

1. **HTML**
2. **CSS**
3. **JAVASCRIPT**
4. Затем приступить к изучению вспомогательных библиотек типа **jQuery, Mootools**
5. Препроцессоры **css (sass, less), js(typescript)**
6. Ну и когда станете гуру в выше перечисленных технологиях можно освоить **Knockout.js, Angular 2, ReactJs, Backbone**

Почему стоит учить в порядке **HTML > CSS > JS**:

Потому, что с **CSS** зависим от **HTML**, а **JS** от **HTML и CSS**, ну а все остальное от первых трех пунктов.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, в таком порядке и начну учить!)
Может подскажете ещё ресурсы, книги, по html и css?

Comment: Пожалуйста ), http://itvdn.com - тут есть курсы по html, css, js довольно доходчиво рассказывают. Кроме того есть https://github.com/Kison/free-programming-books  с бесплатной литературой, но там из интересующего вас материала есть только по js книги.

Answer (score 3):

Для *Frontend* девелоперов желательно знать `HTML`,`CSS` и `JS` вместе. Так как они тесно друг с другом связаны. Да, вы можете сразу начать с Javascript, но лучше будет изучить сперва *`HTML`* и *`CSS`*..

Они довольно легкие, учитывая то что они **НЕ** являются языком программирования, кроме `JS` конечно же. Научиться HTML и CSS можно за пару недель, максимум за месяц.

А вам я посоветую данный сайт [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) Он на английском, но тут полно информации для того чтобы стать фронтенд и даже бакенд девелопером.

Comment: "Научиться HTML и CSS можно за пару недель, максимум за месяц." - а потом интернет кишит говносайтами и заказчики думают, что эта работа ничего не стоит, потому что горекодеры с месячным стажем портят рынок своими громкими обещаниями

Comment: @lexxl Ну я `Basic` Знания имею ввиду) Основам) конечно для того чтобы стать супер фронтендером нужно потратить минимум год) хотябы на HTML и CSS только)

Answer (score 2):

Начать можно с прохождения курсов на https://www.codecademy.com/ или https://htmlacademy.ru/, и дальше смотреть по ощущениям. Если будет слишком просто - углубляться в js, сборщики ассетов, пре- и постпроцессоры и т.д.